# Get the initial selected value of an select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to obtain the original selected value of a `<select>` element as it was written by the initial HTML and defined by `selected="selected"`.  For instance, the original value of mySel is 2 no matter what the user selects.  Or in other words, I would like to get the default value of the `<select>` element similarly as I am doing with the below `<input>` element.  Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $('#click').click(function(){
                    console.log($("#myInput").val(),$("#myInput").attr('value'));
                    console.log($("#mySel").val(),$("#mySel").attr('value'),$('#mySel option:selected').val());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="click">Click</button>
        <input type="text" value="Default Value" id="myInput" name="myInput" class="valid">
        <select id="mySel" name="mySel">
            <option value="1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">Value 2</option>
            <option value="3">Value 3</option>
        </select>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: do you care if it works for `<select multiple>`?

Comment: @zzzzBov.  No, I do not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is specified as an attribute, you can select that:

```
$('#mySel option[selected]');
```

or even

```
$('#mySel [selected]');
```

This will select the original `selected` value no matter what the user has changed it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/szT4w/

Comment: This will of course select all elements with the `[selected]` attribute, which could be an error or could be intentional if it's a `select[multiple]` element. Additionally this will *not* work if there are no `option[selected]` elements, in which case you should fall back to the first `option` element.

Answer (score -1):

Use to get select option of a select element like this:

```
$("#mySel option[selected]").val();
```

It will do the magic :)

Comment: That returns what the user has selected, not necessarily what the HTML originally marked as selected.